# Maximum Form count in Application

Tags: forms, delphi

Is there any limitation on the number of forms in Delphi applications?
I developed an application with 40 or more Forms (with Delphi XE4), and I'm concerned about its performance!

Is it a good idea to create Forms on demand instead of creating all of them at application startup?

Comment: First thing you do is delete all the global form variables. Create forms when you need them, and hold them in local variables if you need a reference. That's  good for modal forms. For non-modal it is less clear cut.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no limitation to the number of Forms, other than available system memory. Forms (and child components) are being kept in `TList` descendants. Theoretically, a TList hás its boundary, but you will hit the limit of system memory, window handle or GDI limits long before, guaranteed.

Yes, it is preferred to create Forms on demand. Creating all Forms at application startup unnecessarily slows down the startup and will consume unnecessary memory, because most likely many Forms will never be used in an application's session. Therefore you should always disable automatic form creation in the [Form Designer Options of the Environment](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Form_Designer_Options). A related issue concerns the global form variables that the IDE adds to form units by default: delete them immediately. Instead, use your own reference-holding mechanism for Forms created.

On existing projects where that option wasn't disabled, you should remove all forms - besides the Main Form - from the auto-create-forms listbox in the [Form Options of the Project](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Forms_%28dialog_box%29). Synonymous to this is removing all `Application.CreateForm(...)` lines from the project file.

Of course, there can be exceptions to this guideline of creating Forms on demand. Some Forms may be used often enough (and may be very expensive to create) to justify their creation once at startup and keeping them alive. Users are more accustomed to a somewhat long taking application startup then a long taking action when it is already active. In this case, keeping the global Form variable could make sense to express its never-ending existence.

Comment: Should I Free Forms on TMain_Form.FormClose event? :-?

Comment: It is probably worth noting that there are obviously going to be exceptions to the guideline of creating forms on demand.  Some forms may be very expensive to create and free and may be used often enough that it makes sense to create them once at startup and keep them alive.

Comment: Quite possible windows handle and GDI limits will be the limiting factor.

Comment: @Jess I think "Where to free Forms and how to keep that sync with its reference" is another question.

Answer (score 1):

I have project with 450 forms and 500 fast reports.I create forms on demand and release it on form close.application startup is 3 seconds.